# Adjusting Factor to as.Date(), pre 1970

Tags: date, time-series, lubridate

Good Morning,

I have successfully pulled monthly market returns from 1900 to present day.  However, I am having issues coercing the date column to something usable.  The original CSV file has the date format as "1-Jan-2000" or "1-Apr-1970".  The time series begins with "1-Oct-33."

I have tried everything but am hitting a road block with lubridate, trying to coerce factors to dates, etc.

How do I adjust only the pre 1970 figures to negatives to correctly plot the data?  Code below:

```
> data <- read.csv("spxhistoricreturns.csv")
> data$Level <- gsub(",","",data$Level)
> data$Level <- gsub(",","",data$Level)
> data$Level <- as.numeric(data$Level)
> class(data$Level)
[1] "numeric"
> class(data$Date)
[1] "factor"
```

I tried lubridate function but the numbers increase after 1970

```
> data$Date <- mdy(data$Date)
> class(data$Date)
[1] "date"
```

So the plot looks like this:

[image]

Please help!

Comment: Any assistance?